# Line calculation from KML file

Tags: qgis, kml, line, length

I am a beginner in QGIS 2 and Mac OSx Mountain Lion
I need to get line length in meters for different gps waypoints.

1 I import kml file to create a new vector shape (this works fine). The projection CRS is WGS84 (as google earth from which KML files are generated).

I went through many posts but it was impossible to get a correct distance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Whne you create the shapefile, choose a CRS that is UTM, not WGS84. QGIS will recognise that the kml is WGS84 and convert to your choice. In that new layer, your calculations should then be in metres.

http://www.icsm.gov.au/mapping/map_projections.html#utm_zones

For instance, I use EPSG:28355.